# Initial value in redux slice not getting updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage, redux-persist

I have a redux slice

`export const initialState = {   name:"",   age:"" }`

I want to add place:"" to my initialState. But in my localstorage persist:root even after adding
`export const initialState = {   name:"",   age:"" ,place:""}` I am not able to see place in persist:root.

In incognito it works. And if i manually clear localstorage then also it works but not getting updated by default.

tried change persist config etc. Nothing seems to be working untill we clear localstorage manually

Comment: That's the expected behaviour, once it's written into localstorage it's no longer initial state but a current state

Comment: @Krzysztof Krzeszewski
 any idea on how to update current state whenever we make changes to initial state.